# AS3 Trigger event with object on top only

Tags: actionscript-3, events, movieclip

I have a bunch of MovieClips layered on top of each other (the same size), and each one has a MouseEvent.CLICK event associated with it. I only want the one on top (I'll be adding more to the list) to trigger and the rest to do nothing (unless the top gets removed, then the new "top" gets the click event).

How would I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to try this. The best in my mind is to keep track, such as with an array, of which buttons are there, in order. Deactivate all but the first one in the array, and any time one is removed, remove it from the array and then activate the first button still in the array.

Comment: I got this to work by removing the current "top" listener before the next one gets loaded. Thanks!